# GScript - Creating copy and move it to a certain folder

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, directory

I'm trying to create copy of a SpreadSheet in different folder but everytime I try, it comes back with some Type error!

I've read through a lot of documentation but most suggestions don't work for me.

My code works like this:

```
var folder2move = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of folder")
motherSheet.makeCopy(folder2move)
```

> TypeError: Cannot find function makeCopy in object Spreadsheet.

Alternatively I tried to create copy anywhere and move the sheet to the folder, but it also does not work:

```
folder2move.addFile(motherSheet)
```

> Cannot find method addFile(Spreadsheet).

The only thing that worked so far is to create a copy of the Spreadsheet in drive at all:

```
motherSheet.copy("Daily Report " + someDateAdd);
```

Please help me. I don't see how to progress.

Comment: Show us your full code,Is your ***motherSheet*** File object or Spreadsheet object?

Comment: Thank you! It was a Spreadsheet object. Once I changed it to file I could apply makeCopy

Comment: If you have the answer, the post the answer.  You can answer you're own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to iJay.

the problem was that I defined `motherSheet` as ***SpreadSheet***.
Once I defined the relevant file as ***File***, the whole `makeCopy` business worked out.

Herefore I used:

```
var fileSearch = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name_motherSheet)
  while (fileSearch.hasNext()) {
   var updatedReport = fileSearch.next();
  }
```

and eventually

```
updatedReport.makeCopy("Daily Report")
```